# pass an arraylist from jsp to action class using struts2

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

I have one jsp page with jqgrid I want to pass that grid data to action class.I am editing jqgrid data using cellEdit and now i want to pass this new data to action class to update this  data in database.How can i pass the jqgrid data from jsp to action class?

```
 <sjg:grid id="gridtable" caption="　" dataType="json" 
                href="%{listurl}"
                gridModel="listMS_AUTONUMBER"
                            cellEdit="true"
                    cellurl="%{cellediturl}">

<sjg:gridColumn frozen="false"  name="autonumberCd" index="autonumberCd" title="%{getText('autonumber.autonumbercode')}"
                    sortable="true" search="true" editable="true" key="true" editoptions="{maxlength :2}"
                    editrules="{required:true,custom:true,custom_func:validateCapitalAlphanumeric}" formatter="String"  formoptions="{elmsuffix:'  *'}"/>     

                <sjg:gridColumn name="autonumberNm" index="autonumberNm" title="%{getText('autonumber.autonumbername')}"
                    sortable="true" editable="true" edittype="text" editrules="{required:true}" editoptions="{maxlength :10}" formoptions="{elmsuffix:'  *'}" />        

                <sjg:gridColumn name="nextAutonumber" index="nextAutonumber" title="%{getText('autonumber.nextautonumber')}"
                    sortable="true" editable="true" edittype="text" editrules="{required:true,custom:true,custom_func:validateNumericOnly}" editoptions="{maxlength :10}" align="right" formoptions="{elmsuffix:'  *'}" />                      
            </sjg:grid>
```

This is my jqgrid in which `listMS_AUTONUMBER` is list which retrieves value from database and coming from another action class.

Comment: what kind of format are you using in the jqgrid? json? You should post code, so people can understand you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the jqgrid data from jsp to action class i am using json as follows:

```
var data=jQuery("#gridtable").jqGrid('getRowData');      //this method gets all the data from grid
var postData = JSON.stringify(data);          //using json stringify convert the data in string format
alert(postData);
```

using alert I am displaying data of jqgrid in string format.

After that I am sending this data to action class through AJAX as follows:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "Get",
    url: "action_name?AutoList="+postData,
    data : {
           jgGridData: postData,
        },
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
});
```

After this in action class, converting this String to json format as follows:

```
JSONArray outerArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(AutoList);
```